# phpdoc how to document @return for both success and fail

Tags: php, phpdoc, docblocks

i'm trying to keep my php rest server properly documents, so i was wondering how do we document that the return value can be one of 2 ?

```
  /**
   * send email to a user that contain reset data
   * it also create reset token, so if there was an old reset token it will be changed
   *
   * @param email $email {@type email"
   * @return SuccessMessage|FailMessage
   */
  public function getSearch($email){
   // search for $email, if success return 
   if($this->doOperation()===true){
     return new SuccessMessage($email);
   }

   return new FailMessage($email);
  }
```

nowing that both FailMessage and SuccessMessage are just empty classes to act as a consistent data structure

something more like this.

```
class FailMessage extends Messages{
  function __construct(string $message, int $uid) {
      if(is_callable("parent::__construct")){
        parent::__construct(...func_get_args());
      }
      $this->uid = $uid;
      $this->message = $data;
   }
}
```

Comment: I see nothing wrong in `SuccessMessage|FailMessage`. What exact problem are you facing? Are you generating HTML documentation or just expecting code intelligence in your IDE?

Comment: What you've written should be good enough.

Comment: I'd use `@return Message` since _both are just empty classes_

Comment: yes i use generators to generate html documentation (Swagger) using luracast restler framework

Comment: I'm curios about `parent::__construct(...func_get_args())`. Can you actually use that to pass along all arguments to another method? I thought that `...` only was for accepting an unknown set of arguments?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yeap you can use spread operator `...` to pass all arguments to parent with exact same order as recived

Comment: @Zalaboza I did not know that. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

```
  /**
   * send email to a user that contain reset data
   * it also create reset token, so if there was an old reset token it will be changed
   *
   * @param email $email {@type email"
   * @return object SuccessMessage|FailMessage
   */
```

Your own comment is Ok but for more you can add object type. Also read the following document from the official website:

[returnTags-PHPDoc](https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/return.html)